# Problems reading files from an S3 bucket mounted to Ubuntu using s3fs

Tags: amazon-s3, fuse, s3fs

I am trying to use sf3f (https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse to handle files being uploaded by a different process to an s3 bucket. I can see files listed when I ls in hat mounted directory and the files are showing correctly timestamped and with the correct size. But trying to open the files either in code or using vi or nano just shows garbage such as
`^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@`

If I curl the s3 link then I do see content so it is available and there do not seem to be permission issues.

I am able to create a new file in this directory and the content is saving fine - can view it in the S3 explorer.

Any thoughts? Is this an s3fs-fuse problem and I may fair better using an alternate such as https://github.com/kahing/goofys?

I have signed up for the AWS EFS preview but no idea what the wait time is for that.

Comment: `^@^@^@` isn't precisely garbage... that's a string of `0x00` (ASCII `NUL`) bytes.  Are you sure the files are intact in S3 (e.g. if you download them from the console)?  I use s3fs-fuse... in production... and have never seen this... So, of course it could be a bug in s3fs, but certainly not one that's just laying around because nobody feels like fixing it.

Comment: thanks @Michael-sqlbot can you share with me the options you are using when calling s3fs? I am wondering if there is an option we should be specifying but am not and that is causing the issue. I did try using goofys to compare and it is working with no trouble but I would like to be able to give some feedback to the s3fs project on what might be causing the break in my case here. Totally agree, this code is used everywhere and so I am sure it is not just a defect that is laying around

Comment: s3fs 1.85 fixes a variety of data corruption issues including #918 which has similar symptoms. Could you test again with a later version?